# How to loop through anchor tags within div tags which have the same class name

Tags: javascript

My header on my website has 5 tabs (they are div tags all named "dropdown". Under each tab are clickable links (the anchor tags). I am trying to write some code that will print text in the console when a link is click and tell the user about where it was clicked (it uses the innerText). For instance, if a user clicks a link under the first tab, it will log "column 1| Link1" or if a user clicks on a link in the second tab "column 2| link 3". All I have is the nested for loop that will loop through the anchor tags under each div tag but I am not sure if its correct. This is what I have:

```
var dropdownDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown');
for(i = 0; i < dropdownDivs.length;i++) {
var lnks = 
document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown').getElementsByTagName('a');
for(i = 0; i < dropdownDivs.length;i++){ 
    for (var l in lnks) {
}};
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Do you have HTML you can post to go with that script?

Comment: Yes I do. I have HTML. But this is a large website and it has a lot of html code. But I am trying to capture analytics in the header of the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the placement index of the DIV and the Link(anchor tag) on the page you're going to need to collect at least one of them into an array to grab their index using the `indexOf` method.

You can use `querySelectorAll` to more easily grab the elements needed to do the work.

Note: `querySelectorAll` returns an HTMLCollection, *not* an Array. They both have a `forEach` method so I just wanted to point this out.

```
// get all anchor elements within an element with the class dropdown
 let collection = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown a");

// iterate over links in elements with dropdown class
// parameters for forEach are (element, index)
  collection.forEach((ele, ind) => {

// we get the parent node(the element with the dropdown class)
// then we figure out what number element(div) we're on by looking at the array
// of all elements with the dropdown class

      let p = ele.parentNode;
      let p_ind = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown')).indexOf(p);

//we add 1 to the indices because there is a 0 index and we 
//would like to start at the first DIV/Link being a 1, not 0

      ind++;
      p_ind++;
//add an event listener to the links that alerts the results
//on click
    ele.addEventListener('click', () => alert("link " + ind + " in div" + p_ind))
    })
```

```js
let collection = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown a");

collection.forEach((ele, ind) => {
let p = ele.parentNode;
let p_ind = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown')).indexOf(p);
ind++;
p_ind++;
ele.addEventListener('click', () => alert("link " + ind + " in div" + p_ind))
})
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 75px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="#">hi</a>
    <a href="#">bye</a>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">hi</a>
    <a href="#">bye</a>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">hi</a>
    <a href="#">bye</a>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">hi</a>
    <a href="#">bye</a>
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#">hi</a>
    <a href="#">bye</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I am trying to do. Is there a way to do without JQuery?

Comment: @PinkNGreen This is just JavaScript actually :)

Comment: Oh i saw Query and automatically  thought it was Jquery. Lol Thanks for your help!

Comment: @PinkNGreen No problem! If this is the answer you're looking for don't forget to check the green checkmark next to my answer so that it helps others out too!

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your code, I'd suggest changing

```
document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown').getElementsByTag‌​Name('a')
```

with

```
dropdownDivs[i].getElementsByTagName('a')
```

I say this because document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown') will return an array again (an array you've already got by the way) rather than the element in question, which would be represented by

```
dropdownDivs[i]
```